# How do I create a class instance from a string name in ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the name of a class and I want to create an instance of that class so that I can loop through each rails attribute that is present in the schema of that class.

How would I go about doing that?

1. I have the name as a string of the class I want to check
2. I guess I need to instantiate a class instance so that I can
3. Loop through it's attributes and print them.

Comment: This is a great question. Thanks for asking it and saving me from using `eval`

Answer (score 258, accepted):

In rails you can just do:

```
clazz = 'ExampleClass'.constantize
```

In pure ruby:

```
clazz = Object.const_get('ExampleClass')
```

with modules:

```
module Foo
  class Bar
  end
end
```

you would use

```
> clazz = 'Foo::Bar'.split('::').inject(Object) {|o,c| o.const_get c}
  => Foo::Bar 
> clazz.new
  => #<Foo::Bar:0x0000010110a4f8>
```

Comment: Note that `Object.const_get('Foo::Bar')` will not work, while `constantize` will.

Comment: Thanks, woke up to ask about that because of an Admin::User issue :) Beat me to it.

Comment: Hey @Wes, this was helpful, thanks! Quick question - would this work for nested modules as well? For example, `clazz = 'Foo::Bar::Uber'`

Comment: @iaacp Yes, it will work for as many nested levels as you have.

Answer (score 19):

Very simple in Rails: use [`String#constantize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-constantize)

```
class_name = "MyClass"
instance = class_name.constantize.new
```

Comment: For Rails not Ruby :(

Comment: Shamelessly copy the [ActiveSupport implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/375a4143cf5caeb6159b338be824903edfd62836/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb#L271) if  you're not using Rails already

Answer (score 7):

```
module One
  module Two
    class Three
      def say_hi
        puts "say hi"
      end
    end
  end
end

one = Object.const_get "One"

puts one.class # => Module

three = One::Two.const_get "Three"

puts three.class # => Class

three.new.say_hi # => "say hi"
```

In ruby 2.0 and, possibly earlier releases, `Object.const_get` will [recursively perform a lookup](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-const_get) on a namespaces like `Foo::Bar`. The example above is when the namespace is known ahead of time and highlights the fact that `const_get` can be called on modules directly as opposed to exclusively on `Object`.

Comment: You should add an explanation to this. As of now, it is only a block of code.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
Kernel.const_get("MyClass").new
```

Then to loop through an object's instance variables:

```
obj.instance_variables.each do |v|
  # do something
end
```

Comment: Thank you, since I really have to loop through the columns of the active record model this won't work for me but it will be useful in my "pure" ruby apps :)

Comment: Check out ActiveRecord#attributes() and/or ActiveRecord#attribute_names().

Comment: Awesome! http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-attributes