# Rails CSV db population

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, csv, carrierwave, uploading

I have this scenario on which i need some design suggestions, maybe a little structure definition:

I have a user that can upload a csv file and based on the contents of that file i have to populate the database, sounds simple-eh!

Ok so far so good, now the thing is that this csv is quite large, i mean it's got some 100+ header fields (sounds crazy) and who knows how many records per file, but anyways, so far we have this csv uploading and db population. But wait, this csv file needs to be classified/categorized on the basis of a field ("DIVISION"). Division is an integer column and based on it's value i need to identify which Division this csv belongs to. So far we have the following requirements:

```
    => CSV file uploading
    => File classification based on div id
    => record insertion
```

The matter is still not resolved yet. Division itself is further classified into two types: REGULAR and PROMO

I've got samples in which i have headers for each type. So we also need to identify now which division type this csv belongs to and then start the processing.

```
    => CSV file uploading
    => File classification based on div id and headers (counting and matching the headers for div-sub type using some already defined hash of headers for each division)
```

So after the identification of the file i.e which division and sub-type the file belongs to i need to do some validations on the fields like, presence and then some format checking etc.

I want to use carrierwave for file uploading and smarter_csv gem for csv processing then some jquery plugin for front-end file processing and uploading progress like jquery.fileupload plugin and some background job integration to do all the processing and type checking in the background.

I need some db design/structure help on this coz i'm a newbie. Any help is much much appreciated, :).

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use smarter_csv to import your CSV-files.

For each of the rows you will get one hash with 100+ key/value pairs, where the keys are the headers in your CSV-file (after possible modifications).

For simplicity, let's say that one of the columns in your CSV file determines which kind of record you want to create in the database, e.g. "division" or "type"

Let's say you try to upload data for Ads to your database from a CSV file, then you need to create the models accordingly.   If your 100+ columns never change names, then it's probably best to model this with Single Table Inheritance (STI):

```
 class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
 ...
 end

 class  AdRegular < Ad
 end

 class AdPromo < Ad
 end
```

In the controller for the uploads you need to do something like this:

```
 require 'smarter_csv'{:chunk_size => 1} ) do |array|
   row_hash = array.first 
   case row_hash[:type]
   when 'regular'
      AdRegular.create( row_hash )
   when 'promotion'
      AdPromo.create( row_hash )
   else
      puts "ERROR, unexpected :type in CSV file: #{row_hash[:type]}"
   end
 end
```

You could also create the class name from the string `row_hash[:type]` and then do a `create` call on the resulting class

See also: [Create Class from String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924495/how-do-i-create-a-class-instance-from-a-string-name-in-ruby)