# How to use polymorphism to remove a switch statement which compares strings?

Tags: ruby, json, reflection, polymorphism

I am new to Ruby, so let me describe the context of my problem first:
I have a json as input which has the following key / value pair:

```
{
 "service": "update"
}
```

The value has many different values for example: insert,delete etc.
Next there is a method x which handles the different requests:

```
def x(input)

  case input[:service]      
  services = GenericService.new

  when "update"
    result = services.service(UpdateService.new,input)
  when "insert"
    result = services.service(InsertService.new,input)
  when "delete"
    result = services.service(DeleteService.new,input)
  ....
  ....
  else
    raise "Unknown service"
  end
  puts JSON.pretty_generate(result)    
end
```

What is bothering me is that I still need to use a switch statement to check the String values (reminds me of 'instance of' ugh..). Is there a cleaner way (not need to use a switch)?

Finally I tried to search for an answer to my question and did not succeed, if however I missed it feel free to comment the related question.

**Update:** I was thinking to maybe cast the string to the related class name as follows: [How do I create a class instance from a string name in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924495/how-do-i-create-a-class-instance-from-a-string-name-in-ruby) and then call result = services.services(x.constantize.new,input) , then the class names ofcourse needs to match the input of the json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
def x(input)

  service_class_name = "#{input[:service].capitalize}Service"
  service_class = Kernel.const_get(service_class_name)
  service_class.new(input).process

end
```

In addition you might want to check if this is a valid Service class name at all.

I don't understand why you want to pass the service to `GenericService` this seems strange. let the service do it's job.

Comment: GenericService becomes neglect now, because I can directly call update,insert etc.

Comment: how can it be achieved to limit the Kernal.const_get to a specific module Y?

Comment: Nevermind got it :) Object.const_get(module_name).const_get(class_name).new

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to instatiate a class by it's name you're actually speaking about Reflection rather than Polymorphism.

In Ruby you can achieve this in this way:

```
byName = Object.const_get('YourClassName')
```

or if you are in a Rails app

```
byName= 'YourClassName'.constantize
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Just first thoughts, but you can do:

```
eval(services.service("#{input[:service].capitalize}Service.new, #{input})") if valid_service? input[:service]

def valid_service?
    w%(delete update insert).include? input[:service]
end
```

As folks will no doubt shout, eval needs to be used with alot of care

Comment: Neverever use "eval". It is "evil".

Comment: @pascalbetz - I would agree you can get yourself into alot of trouble with eval, I prefer the the const_get as it'll just throw an error if you try grabbing something that doesn't exist, hence the need for the sanity check on inbound.