# Convert symbol into an object

Tags: ruby

My method takes an argument. I prefer to avoid directly passing the object like so:

```
def print_error(Loggers::MyLogger.new, error)
  ...
end
```

Instead, I would like to pass a symbol like so:

```
def print_error(:my_logger, error)
  ...
end
```

Is there an elegant way to convert `:my_logger` symbol into a `MyLogger` instance? Or do I have to build a factory mechanism for that?

Comment: What is the logic you are using to "convert the `Symbol` into an object"?

Comment: @JörgWMittag Sorry, I'm not sure I understand the question. You want to know the reason I'm asking for an object in the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails there is a helper ready for that [`constantize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize):

```
:my_logger.to_s.camelize.constantize
#⇒ MyLogger
```

In Ruby one might do it using [`Module#const_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-const_get):

```
klazz = :my_logger.to_s.gsub(/(\A|_)(.)/) { |m| m[-1].upcase }
const_get(klazz) if const_defined?(klazz)
#⇒ MyLogger
```

Comment: What is the reason for looking up the constant in `Kernel` instead of, say, `Object` or the current scope or the `Logger` module?

Comment: @JörgWMittag No reason, I just put it for clarity. If you think it messes things up, I will remove it.

Comment: You should remove the Rails part. The OP is asking for a non-Rails solution (and it doesn't work anyway).

Comment: @Stefan what exactly does not work? I think that `Inflector` might be used in non-rails projects, and it is a good reference to take a look at how it was implemented.

Comment: Thank you mudasobwa, It work :-) (at least the Ruby method of doing so, I don't use rails do I wasn't able to test `constantize`).

Comment: @mudasobwa `constantize` expects a proper constant name, it doesn't automatically convert to camel case.

Comment: @Stefan indeed, thanks, updated. I decided to leave the [corrected] rails answer as well for the sake of consistency for the future visitors who might be interested in rails way as well.

Answer (score 1):

First, we transform `:my_logger` into a string "MyLogger" (ref : [Converting string from snake_case to CamelCase in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524457/converting-string-from-snake-case-to-camel-case-in-ruby) ) :

```
camel_str = :my_logger.to_s.camelize
```

Then we use the string with the name of the class to create the object (ref : [How do I create a class instance from a string name in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924495/how-do-i-create-a-class-instance-from-a-string-name-in-ruby) ):

```
obj = Object.const_get(camel_str)
```

So putting everything together :

```
camel_str = :my_logger.to_s.camelize  
obj = Object.const_get(camel_str)
```

Comment: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'camelize' for "my_logger":String`

Comment: camelize is in rails, sorry I was thinking you were using it.

Comment: Thanks Pholochtairze. Sadly as I mentioned I'm not using Rails, so `camelize` does not work.

Answer (score -1):

Well, if it's about converting a symbol into it's corresponding class (if exists!), how about this one:

```
class Symbol
  def to_ob
    eval(self.to_s)
  end
end

:String.to_ob        #=>String
```