# can I use a variable name in the place of an object name in ruby

Tags: ruby

Recently, I just wrote a simple game in Ruby. I needed the user to input a object's name which I created earlier.

When I give the variable name in the place of object's name, ruby thinks it is another string and outputs that

> there is no such method(no method error)

How can I solve this?

```
class game
  #somecode
  def weapon_power
    @power
  end
end

object = game.new
x = gets #user inputs object
puts x.weapon_power
```

Answer (score 1):

You set the variable `x` to the return value of the [`gets`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) method. This method always returns a `String` object.

Now, in your code, you are trying to call the `weapon_power` method on this `String` object which naturally fails since Strings don't have such a method.

I'm not exactly sure what you want to achieve here in the first place though, but you can call the `weapon_power` method on your `object` like this:

```
object.weapon_power
```

As a final note, please be aware that in Ruby, class names (like your `game` always have to start with a capital letter. It thus has to be spelled `Game` instead. With your exact code, you would have received a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking how to instantiate your `Game` object via it's name in a string.

```
x = gets
clazz = Object.const_get(x)
obj = clazz.new
```

If the class is already instantiated you'll have to do more work. Maybe something like this

```
gameInstance = Game.new

x = gets
case x
when 'Game'
    puts gameInstance.weapon_power
else
    puts 'Unknown input'
end
```

Possible duplicate of: [How do I create a class instance from a string name in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924495/how-do-i-create-a-class-instance-from-a-string-name-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% I undestand what you want - looks like using the user input to identify a variable, correct?

If so, an easy way would be through a Hash:

```
object = game.new

objects = { "object" => object }
x = gets #user inputs object
puts objects[x].weapon_power # retrieve object named "object" and call the weapon-power on it
```

Benefit is that this would work with several objects in the Hash if needed.