# How to instatiate the class by dynamically receiving the class name

Tags: ruby

I need to create a class but the condition is, I will receive the class name in strings like shown below

```
 ["IndividualContact", "Legal"].each do |var|
      ind = var.new
    end
```

Now My expectation is, I need to call

`IndividualContact.new` and `Legal.new` but since var is a string variable, it's calling `.new` on a string like given below

```
"IndividualContact".new
```

rather than calling

```
IndividualContact.new
```

Is there any way can I call as I expected?

Comment: This has been answered before here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924495/how-do-i-create-a-class-instance-from-a-string-name-in-ruby

Comment: @Sixty4Bit the mentioned answer is unrelated since it uses the method that is not existing in Ruby.

Comment: @mudasobwa it uses const_get just as your answer does. How is that not a part of Ruby? Look at the second example.

Comment: @Sixty4Bit ah, indeed, will close this as a dup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Module#const_get`](https://ruby-doc.org/Module.html#method-i-const_get) (assuming these classes are already defined in the global namespace):

```
%w|IndividualContact Legal|.map do |klazz|
  Kernel.const_get(klazz).new
end
```

The code above will return an array containing two instances: one instance of `IndividualContact` and one of `Legal`.

Comment: You would not need to use const_get with your code because you are passing in constants. If you were passing in Strings then this would work.

Comment: @Sixty4Bit excuse me? I am passing strings.

Comment: perfect, works perfectly!

Comment: Apologies. Missed the %w.

Comment: might mention that these classes need to be defined in the current context because when I read the title and this fragment *"I need to create a class..."* I was a assuming the OP was looking for `Class.new` and `const_set`

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks, updated.